# Not getting relay candidates or not connected by turn server in WebRTC Android

Tags: android, webrtc, video-conferencing, webrtc-android

I am building a video conferencing application based on webRTC in android. For using webRTC in android, I am using the following  webRTC  dependency in android

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.28513'
```

Everything is working fine. One to One and multipart conferencing is done without any issue.

But when I joined by the turn server then I am getting IceConnectionState.FAILED. And When I check icecnadidates sometimes I got relay candidates but sometimes not. I didn't find the root cause for this.

Could you please help me to resolve this issue? Why I am not getting relay candidates sometimes and also why I am not connected via turn server.

Thanks,
Shashank

Comment: Managed to solve the issue?